# Are hot stars like O-type stars entirely composed of helium?

Tags: star, spectra, hydrogen, helium

Hot stars like [O-type stars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O-type_star) show no hydrogen in their [spectra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_classification). Does this mean they are made entirely of helium?

Any explanation would be really helpful.

Comment: You missed this sentence from the Wikipedia article you cited: 

*Stars of this type are identified by their dominant Helium II absorption lines, strong lines of **other ionised elements**, and **Hydrogen** and neutral He lines weaker than spectral type B.* 

(Emphasis added)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lines that appear in a stars spectrum mainly reflects its temperature not its composition, [see here](http://www.star.ucl.ac.uk/~pac/spectral_classification.html)

O-type stars start out with the same sort of [composition as other stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundance_of_the_chemical_elements#Abundance_of_elements_in_the_Universe), that is they are mainly H and He (approximately 75% and 25% by mass) with traces heavier elements.